# wxPython: Toolbar Menu close event

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython

I am creating a python app with wxPython 2.9.5 which features a system tray icon with a menu. I would like to receive an event when the menu is hidden/closed. On the mac the wx.EVT_TASKBAR_* event are not triggered. What event is there that I could Bind to?

I am asking as I want to toggle between a black and white icon on a mac.

https://gist.github.com/thomaschaaf/49e64bf2aa7c3078ede3

Update 1:
Attaching the binding to the app instead makes the event trigger on mac. Here is the example working like I want.

https://gist.github.com/thomaschaaf/7344891

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are creating the popup menu the normal way? Something like this:

```
menu = wx.Menu()
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_RESTORE, "Open Program")
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_CHANGE, "Show all the Items")
menu.AppendSeparator()
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_CLOSE,   "Exit Program")
```

Well normally you'll also see a

```
menu.Destroy()
```

You should add a method call right after that so that your code looks something like this in the end:

```
menu = wx.Menu()
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_RESTORE, "Open Program")
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_CHANGE, "Show all the Items")
menu.AppendSeparator()
menu.Append(self.TBMENU_CLOSE,   "Exit Program")
menu.Destroy()
self.onMenuDestroy()
```

Then you just add whatever needs to be done in the onMenuDestroy method.